# Should production server have SSH key on developer's private github account?

Tags: git, github, ssh, server, public-key

I have a private github repo that can obviously only be accessed with the correct credentials.  Currently I have created a public SSH key on the production server and added that to one of the developers github accounts.  This then allows us to pull in new code from the private github repo.

Now the obvious issue is that if the developer leaves the company, any further pulls will not work.  I wanted to know what is the best practice for ensuring that a live/production server pulls in code from a private github repo.

Comment: The best practice is that you shouldn't deploy to production straight away by pulling from a repo. Use CDD pipeline instead.

Comment: Are you sure you put the public key on the production server, not the private one

Comment: The best practice is to not rely on a developer's private repo for production-ready code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't rely on a developer's private repo for deployment. Any code owned by the company needs to be in a repository that is accessible by several people so that there is not a single point of failure.
2. Use a Continuous Integration/Continuous Deployment pipeline for deployment rather than deploying directly from the repo with a pull. [(As stated in comments by @marekful.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51406336/should-production-server-have-ssh-key-on-developers-private-github-account#comment89783989_51406336)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out (and @marekful too).  I've been developing for years and somehow this has passed me by.  I'd love to look more into this but the problem is we have only a few tests (I feel having this CDD pipeline only works if you have enough tests). I need to read up more on this but where/how will this "CDD" get access to the private repo from?

Comment: @JohnCrawford I'm not familiar with the details. I suggest starting by setting up a CI environment that checks that your code has no syntax errors. From there you can add tests. Even a few tests that pass are better than none.

Comment: @JohnCrawford More importantly, tests should be designed to fail when critical parts of your code have errors. Just a few of these can help catch serious problems before they are deployed to production.

Comment: I've just bumped into Continuous Delivery vs. Continuous Deployment vs. Continuous Integration... previously I thought Travis-CI was everything, now I'm not too sure, haha.  I'll most certainly do more reading up on this.  But for now it looks like some sort of pipeline is indeed strongly recommended and not a private/personal github account of a current employee.

Comment: @JohnCrawford Code in a employee's personal github also raises issues with  ownership of intellectual property that I'm sure you want to avoid as well.